# Can I move / Modify the Object in Object Storage Service (OSS)

Tags: storage, cloud

I am using Alibaba Cloud - ECS and have Storage Bucket - Object Storage Service (OSS).

File Storage structure is like

```
oss:/bucket/abc/xyz/123.jpg/
```

My Question is

Can I move or modify the objects in OSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stored files in OSS do not have a directory structure, and the OSS directory structure we see is a simulation with “/“.

If a file on OSS **(oss:/bucket/123/456/789.jpg/)**  ends with “/“, it is recognized as a directory.

That is why moving an object follows the same principle with renaming an object: you need to manually upload the object to the new path location, and delete the old file (to delete the directory, first delete the files under it).

For more details [click here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/39622.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There is no real *edit* functionality, however it can be mimicked by simply uploading a new copy that will then replace the old one.

Reference: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31827.htm, relevant part:

> The stored objects cannot be modified directly. If you want to modify an object, you must upload the new object of the same name to replace the existing one.

The same is true for *moving*: upload it to its new location, then remove the old one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify an object, you must upload a new object with the same name as the existing one to replace it. Therefore, unlike the file system, OSS does not allow users to modify objects directly. so you can only mimic it. You can reaffirm it using their [Official Documentation](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31827.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.19.79bb54bcwDM2Tf).

Hope this answer may help you.